# How to add dash and commas between integers with Python

Tags: python

I have a list of numbers that I would like to display to the end user in a concise readable format.  Here is an example:

```
  >>> display_range( [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12,13, 15, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24 ] )
  '1-10,12,13,15,19-22,24'
```

I found a similar question, but it was for SQL:

[How to add a dash between running numbers and comma between non-running numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56527768/how-to-add-a-dash-between-running-numbers-and-comma-between-non-running-numbers)

I was able to use a concept I saw in that post to write this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


def display_range( values ):
  '''
  Summarizes a sequence of integers for display.

  >>> display_range( [1,2] )
  '1,2'
  >>> display_range( [1,3,6] )
  '1,3,6'
  >>> display_range( [1] )
  '1'
  >>> display_range( [] )
  ''
  >>> display_range( [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12,13, 15, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24 ] )
  '1-10,12,13,15,19-22,24'
  '''


  if not values or len(values) == 0:
    return ''
  if len(values) == 1:
    return str(values[0])

  values.sort()

  start = 0
  end = 0 
  result=''
  wasinrange = False
  for end in range( 1, len(values) ):
    inrange =  values[end] - values[start] == end - start
    if not inrange :
      if wasinrange:
        if end - start > 2:
          result = f"{result},{values[start]}-{values[end-1]}"
        else:
          result = f"{result},{values[start]},{values[end-1]}"
      else:
          result = f"{result},{values[start]}"
      start = end

    wasinrange = inrange


  if inrange:
    if end - start > 2:
      result = f"{result},{values[start]}-{values[-1]}"
    else:
      result = f"{result},{values[start]},{values[-1]}"
  else:
      result = f"{result},{values[-1]}"

  return(result[1:])
```

The good news is that the code works.  You can run the examples for yourself like this:

```
python3 -m doctest -v display_range.py
```

There is a little extra complexity because "ranges" containing only 2 numbers are to be displayed with a comma rather than a dash (e.g. '12,13' instead of '12-13').

The bad news is that the code is awful and admittedly I'm tired of it.  Since it works, it's good enough for me so I'm moving on.  However, since a python solution wasn't in SO I'm sharing this bit of code.  Hopefully, someone can suggest a library that already does this or point me to a better answer in SO.

Of course, it would be great if someone will improve on the code (or rewrite it completely).  My code is repetitive and it has side effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A much shorter way to do it, using some `itertools`:

we use `groupby` to group the contiguous numbers. The key we use is the difference between the item value and a `count` that increments for each item: it will have a constant value in groups of contiguous integers.

The rest is just presentation.

```
from itertools import groupby, count

def display_range(lst):
    idx = count()
    groups = [list(group) for key, group in groupby(sorted(lst), key=lambda item: item - next(idx))]
    out = [f'{g[0]}{",-"[len(g) > 2]}{g[-1]}' if len(g)>1 else str(g[0]) for g in groups]
    return ','.join(out)

display_range([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12,13, 15, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24])
# '1-10,12,13,15,19-22,24'
```

---

To answer your comment, here is a modified version that treats groups of length 2 as you expected:

```
from itertools import groupby, count

def format_group(group):
    group = [str(v) for v in group]
    if len(group) == 1:
        return group[0]
    elif len(group) == 2:
        return ', '.join(group)
    else:
        return f'{group[0]}-{group[-1]}'
    
def display_range(lst):
    idx = count()
    groups = [list(group) for key, group in groupby(lst, key=lambda item: item - next(idx))]
    return ', '.join(map(format_group, groups))


display_range([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12,13, 15, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24])
# '1-10, 12, 13, 15, 19-22, 24'
```

Comment: That's great!  There a lot of new (to me) techniques in there so I appreciate the answer a lot.  The code doesn't 100% meet the requirements ( e.g. 12-13 should be 12,13 ).  Is there a way of writing the last list comprehension to handle three cases ( len(g) > 2, len(g) > 1 and len(g) == 1 ) ?   I've already written an if clause ( using out.append() etc. ) but I'm wondering if there is one more trick you can show me?

Comment: It might be better to have a function to do the formatting, then. See the edit!

Comment: Considering your statement, "the rest is presentation", I made a quick edit to your first bit of code to inline the presentation of the small groups.  Thanks for also addressing the comment.

Comment: @Mark `",-"[len(g) > 2]` would also work (but yours is probably more readable and faster).

Comment: Updated Thierry's original code to include @superbrain 's edit and to add sorted().

Answer (score 1):

An iterator version of Thierry Lathuille's solution that doesn't build lists of all the groups and doesn't convert all elements to strings (only those that go into the output):

```
from itertools import groupby, count

def format_group(group):
    first = next(group)
    for second in group:
        for last in group:
            for last in group:
                pass
            return f'{first}-{last}'
        return f'{first},{second}'
    return str(first)
    
def display_range(lst):
    idx = count()
    groups = (group for _, group in groupby(lst, key=lambda item: item - next(idx)))
    return ','.join(map(format_group, groups))

print(display_range([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12,13, 15, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24]))
```

Output:

```
1-10,12,13,15,19-22,24
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's another similar bit of code that satisfies the requirements, although it's still a little repetitive.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
def display_range( a ):
  '''
  Summarizes a sequence of integers for display.

  >>> display_range( [1,2] )
  '1,2'
  >>> display_range( [1,3,6,7,8] )
  '1,3,6-8'
  >>> display_range( [1] )
  '1'
  >>> display_range( [] )
  ''
  >>> display_range( [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12,13, 15, 19, 20, 21, 22, 24 ] )
  '1-10,12,13,15,19-22,24'
  '''
  a.sort()

  last = -1
  inrange = False
  result = ''
  for x,value in enumerate(a):
    inrange =  value - x == last
    if not inrange :

      if x > 0:
        if a[x-1] != lastvalue:
          if a[x-1] - lastvalue > 1:
            result = f"{result}-{a[x-1]}"
          else:
            result = f"{result},{a[x-1]}"

      if x == 0:
        result=str(value)
      else:
        result=f"{result},{value}"
      lastvalue = value
      last = value - x

  if inrange:
        if a[-1] - lastvalue > 1:
          result=f"{result}-{a[-1]}"
        else:
          result=f"{result},{a[-1]}"

  return(result)
```